# Rails: How to handle associations among namespaced models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, associations

I am trying to figure out what's the best way to handle namespaced models. Here's the models that i have in my project:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ledger, inverse_of: :member, class_name: "Member::Ledger", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ledger_entries, through: :ledger
end

class Member::Ledger < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member, inverse_of: :ledger
  has_many :ledger_entries, foreign_key: "member_ledger_id", dependent: :destroy
end

class Member::LedgerEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ledger, foreign_key: "member_ledger_id"
end
```

And here's how my migrations files look like:

```
create_table :members do |t|
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :member_ledgers do |t|
  t.references :member, foreign_key: true, null: false, index: { unique: true }
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :member_ledger_entries do |t|
  t.references :member_ledger, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.timestamps
end
```

So I have few questions here:

- Are migration files correct? I mean should i have member_ledger_id in the member_ledger_entries table or just ledger_id?
- Are associations defined in a correct way? Even though this works but i am not sure this is how we are supposed to proceed.

I am using ruby-2.5.1 and rails-5.2.0.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your associations could look more like:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :member_ledger, inverse_of: :member, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :member_ledger_entries, through: :member_ledger
end

class Member::Ledger < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member, inverse_of: :member_ledger
  has_many :member_ledger_entries, dependent: :destroy
end

class Member::LedgerEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member_ledger
end
```

Comment: I agree but then the using namespaced models doesn't make much sense. For ex: if i need to fetch all the entries for a member now i need to call member.member_ledger_entries which seems odd. The current associations that i  have i can simply call member.ledger_entries.

Comment: Yes. So, it's basically a matter of preference. If you prefer the cleanliness of `member.ledger_entries`, then my feeling is that your OP is quite good.

Comment: Can you please help me out with the first question?

Comment: BTW, I would leave your database structured the way you have it. Your current approach is conventional (good!) and requires less care (IMO) when setting up your associations.

Comment: I have decided to update the member_ledger_entries table to use reference "ledger" instead of "member_ledger". After going through some articles i realised reference should be based to how you want to define your belongs_to association. In my case as ledger_entry belongs_to ledger so i guess this is the way to go. Also using this simplified my models. Earlier i need to specify foreign_keys but now rails automatically detects it.